Почему ts_rank дает 0 в postgresql
Всем привет! Я использую ts_rank в Postgres 16.2 для получения ранжирования при упоминании ключевых слов и я озадачен. Я предполагал, что на четвертой строчке ранг будет > 0 так как в description есть "стульями", а также в 1 и 2 строчках (name) также содержит "стула", что должно давать rank > 0. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

Проверьте свой default_text_search_config

Нужно было первым аргументом функции to_tsvector('russian', ...)
